# Does QComboBox::count() include separators in the count?

Tags: c++, qt, count, qcombobox

If I do:

```
QComboBox *cb = ...; 

cb->clear();
cb->addItem(...);
cb->insertSeparator(1);
cb->addItem(...);
```

Is `cb->count()` going to return `2` or `3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QComboBox::AddItem` is a shortcut to insert an item in the last position; the default insert method is `QComboBox::InsertItem` which is invoked by `AddItem` and increment the items count; `QComboBox::InsertSeparator` invokes `InsertItem` so, yes, a separator count as an item

Answer (score 3):

The separators [count](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Count_von_Count_kneeling.png). The `count()` will be equal to 3.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QComboBox cb;
   cb.addItem("Foo");
   cb.insertSeparator(1);
   cb.addItem("Bar");
   Q_ASSERT(cb.count() == 3);
   return 0;
}
```